# How to save TextView Values in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How to save TextView values in SharedPreferences, see my code below and let me know how to store to SharedPreferences and retrieve in onCreate(..)

my code looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        txtOperative = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentOperative);
        txtEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentEvent);

        intent = getIntent();
        strEventName = intent.getStringExtra("eventName");
        strOperativeName = intent.getStringExtra("operativeName");

        txtEvent.setText(strEventName);
        txtOperative.setText(strOperativeName);         
    }
```

**I want to show these values always in TextViews, whenever user comes back to this activity**

Comment: where you are saving values in `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: I guess using this: txtEvent.setText(prefs.getString("autoSaveEvent", strEventName)); actually i don't know how to save values in SharedPreferences...just trying to implement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple use this for save your TextView value in sharedpreference

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
 sedt.putString("textvalue", txtEvent.getText().toString());
 sedt.putString("txtopertaive", txtOperative.getText().toString());
 sedt.commit();
```

Now after that retrieve it anywhere in your Activity class or any other Activity by

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
 String tValue = sp.getString("textvalue","");
 String tOperative = sp.getString("txtopertaive","");
```

Comment: can you show me the way by doing changes in my existing code ?

Comment: Which textview value do you want to save?

Comment: I have only two TextViews: txtEvent and txtOperative

Comment: i don't want to get anywhere, i want to put these values for lifetime in these textviews

Comment: But whenever you have in this activity you always see that values.

Comment: I tried this but my issue is still there, whenever i close my app properly from my device and then again launch app not getting values why?

Comment: @AbrahimNeil If you are trying to uninstall app from your device then your data which will be in Shared preference will be deleted.

Comment: @AbrahimNeil So show me that activity from which you can access this strEventName = intent.getStringExtra("eventName");
        strOperativeName = intent.getStringExtra("operativeName");

Comment: @AbrahimNeil Show me that code from which you can start this activity with intent.putExtra.

Answer (score 1):

To save the data, Can't see any call for `SharedPreferences` - `editor`/ `editor.commit()`

Add those functions to your activity:

When you want to save data:

```
saveDataToPreferences(context, "strEventName", valueHere);
```

And in your activity,

```
Context context;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    context=this;

        txtOperative = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentOperative);
        txtEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentEvent);

        intent = getIntent();
        strEventName = intent.getStringExtra("eventName");
        strOperativeName = intent.getStringExtra("operativeName");

        txtEvent.setText(getDataFromPreferences(context,"strEventName"));
        txtOperative.setText(getDataFromPreferences(context,"strEventName"));

    }

    public static void saveDataToPreferences(Context context, String key,
            String value) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("your package name",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static String getDataFromPreferences(Context context, String key) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("your package name",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString(key, Constants.BLANK);
    }
```

Comment: can you show me the way by doing changes in my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

To store in shared preferences your value use that code.

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("OPERATIVE", txtOperative.getText().toString());
 editor.String("EVENT", txtEvent.getText().toString());
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: can you show me the way by doing changes in my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
prefs.edit().putString(context.getString(R.string.NAME), name).commit();
```

in order to save data to shared preferences and

```
prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.NAME), "");
```

to get data from shared preferences.

Comment: can you show me the way by doing changes in my existing code ?

Comment: Please clarify what you want since you have changed the code in your question again.

Answer (score 0):

define Editor like below

```
private Editor editor;
```

and initialize it after initializing shared preference like

```
editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putString("key1", "value1");
editor.putString("key2", "value2");
editor.commit();
```

And to retrieve this value just call

```
String value = prefs.getString("key1","");
```

Comment: can you show me the way by doing changes in my existing code?